# Dont close console (c#)

Tags: c#

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "sdsss" "aa" "bb");
```

The process starts new console and trying to run ras, but when connection 
fails it closes - how to keep the console on the screen?

Comment: I guess you could run `cmd /k rasdial.exe` instead.

Comment: Have you tried adding in a Console.Readline() to your Connection failed handler?

Comment: If you cannot modify the executable, then you can run it over cmd, or simply start exploring the ProcessStartInfo options, and start your executable with that. ProcessStartInfo class has a couple of fields that could help.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve that is to simply redirect the standard error.
This is a simple example.

```
namespace AnswerOne
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //we use a prosessstartinfo 
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("rasdial.exe");
            procInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            //must be false
            procInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            process.StartInfo = procInfo;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();

            string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            //check if there is any error
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(error);
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

More info:[msdn for standard error redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx)